# RuntimeError:freeze_support() on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I'm new on python. I want to learn how to parallel processing in python. I saw the following example:

---

```
import multiprocessing as mp

np.random.RandomState(100)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[20, 5])
data = arr.tolist()

def howmany_within_range_rowonly(row, minimum=4, maximum=8):
    count = 0
    for n in row:
    if minimum <= n <= maximum:
        count = count + 1
    return count

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

results = pool.map(howmany_within_range_rowonly, [row for row in data])

pool.close()

print(results[:10])
```

---

but when I run it, this error happened:

```
RuntimeError: 
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you place everything in global scope inside this `if __name__ == "__main__"` block as follows, you should find that your program behaves as you expect:

```
def howmany_within_range_rowonly(row, minimum=4, maximum=8):
    count = 0
    for n in row:
    if minimum <= n <= maximum:
        count = count + 1
    return count

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    np.random.RandomState(100)
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[20, 5])
    data = arr.tolist()  
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    results = pool.map(howmany_within_range_rowonly, [row for row in data])

    pool.close()

    print(results[:10])
```

Without this protection, if your current module was imported from a different module, your multiprocessing code would be executed. This could occur within a non-main process spawned in another Pool and spawning processes from sub-processes is not allowed, hence we protect against this problem.

Comment: Has this changed recently? I have never seen this error. I recently installed python on a new mac, using miniconda and it appears by default if I do not protect the code under if __name__ == "__main__":

It is a bit annoying since some files are meant to just be executed, not imported, hence the protection and the extra indentation is somewhat confusing

Comment: @andy,yes it has to be new. This guy ran the code an year ago on mac and no error. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso
For me its occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I had a live example, where I faced [the same RuntimeError issue](https://github.com/biocompibens/ALFA/issues/11) when I executed a specific tool on MacOS-machines (on Linux machines it was fine though). However, I'm not sure about the exact cause for the problem, cause the `if __name__ == "__main__"` encapsulation seemed to be properly at place.

Following one comment on this [Stack-Overflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748966/what-is-the-difference-between-spawn-start-method-and-default-macos-start-meth), I suspected that using `python>=3.8`, which utilizes `spawn` as default method for calling subprocesses might be the problem.

**My solution:**
Using `python=3.7` did the trick.