# What is the difference between ‘spawn’ start method and default MacOS start method in multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using  Python  3.7.5. I have this code. It works on my macbook.

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as p:
    func = partial(doc_sentiment_computation_en, analyser=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer())
    documents_with_scores = p.map(func, all_responses)
```

However, this did not work in the production server and I suspected it was because the default start method is fork() in the linux machine in the server. So I tried using the ’spawn’ context. However, it does not work in my mac. Isn’t what I had by default on macOS was ’spawn’ context anyway?

```
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
with ctx.Pool(processes=ctx.cpu_count()) as p:
    func = partial(doc_sentiment_computation_en, analyser=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer())
    documents_with_scores = p.map(func, all_responses)
```

I am new to multiprocessing, so please be kind with me.

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), `spawn` only became the default for macOS since Python 3.8. When using `spawn`, code that creates processes must be within a block governed by `if __name__ == '__main__':`, which is not necessary for `fork`. Why the code does not work for linux is still a question. Then again, you did not post *what* the error is or anything close to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Booboo Your comment solved my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60691363/runtimeerrorfreeze-support-on-mac/73975826#73975826). Setting the python version to 3.7 did the trick for me. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As @Booboo pointed out, spawn became dafault on macOS only in Python3.8, so it was not the case. I was later able to test on a local linux machine, and it worked there too. So it looks like something to do with the server. I was able to solve this by adding p.close() and p.join(). I don’t know the reason. I thought ‘with’ statement would itself ensures proper acquisition and release of resource.

```
with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as p:
        func = partial(find_set_intersection, set_2=search_keywords_lemmas)
        common_lemmas = p.map(func, all_responses_lemmas)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```